# Using jquery to insert data into an input box, but it does not POST to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There is an input box in a form in my page

```
<input name="bid_price" id="bid_price" class="form-control">
```

If I input a value manually , it can post the value

However, if I use the jquery to insert value into it, it doesn't post anything, even I have already inserted it  into the input box in the frontend

```
        $("#optionsRadiosInline3").on("click", function() {
            $("#bid_price").val(<?php echo $product_info['buy_price']; ?>);
            $("#bid_price").prop('disabled', true);
        });
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#bid_price").prop('disabled', true);
```

Don't do that. Disabled controls cannot be successful so they won't be submitted with the form.

You might consider using `readonly` or using a hidden input instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are disabling your input field which restricts data to post.

```
$("#bid_price").prop('disabled', true);
```

Remove this line. 
You can make it readonly to avoid user interference !!

Comment: Correct, but how can I dynamiclly disable the user to modify the value then? Thanks for helping